# Subscriber Android from C++ node

Tags: ros, ros-hydro, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everybody!
I tried to use the rosTextView of Android to display messages from a topic. The publisher is on my computer (ROS Hydro, rqt).
There is no effect (the application doesn't crash), I just get this error :

```
E/UpdatePublisherRunnable﹕ org.ros.internal.node.xmlrpc.XmlRpcTimeoutException: org.apache.xmlrpc.client.TimingOutCallback$TimeoutException: No response after waiting for 10000 milliseconds.
I/dalvikvm﹕ Jit: resizing JitTable from 4096 to 8192

    rosTextView = (RosTextView<std_msgs.String>) findViewById(R.id.text);
    rosTextView.setMessageType(std_msgs.String._TYPE);
    rosTextView.setTopicName("/textView");
    rosTextView.setMessageToStringCallable(new MessageCallable<String, std_msgs.String>() {
        @Override
        public String call(std_msgs.String message) {
            return "ok";
        }
    });
```

This code worked last month and since I might have update some part of ROS, there is a bug.

Have anyone experience this case?
Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/168271/subscriber-android-from-c++-node/) by [thomasL](https://answers.ros.org/users/16906/thomasl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2014-05-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) on 2014-05-25**:
Hasn't been any changes in hydro, rosjava nor I suspect roscpp. Has your android build environment/sdk changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Android Studio has been recently update (version 0.5.7). I'm also unable to create a Client (Android) / Server (Computer) Service as in this post : http://answers.ros.org/question/55922/service-in-android/

---

Originally posted by [thomasL](https://answers.ros.org/users/16906/thomasl/) with karma: 36 on 2014-05-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0